# SQL2012: query to sum based on two arguments that might be the same?

Tags: sql

**FeeTable (zip~fee)**:
91324~60
91326~80

**input**:
@zip1 = 91324
@zip2 = 91324

**desired output**:
120

Not sure if there's a way to code a stored procedure without using a union. Here's what I've been doing:

```
select sum(fee) from 
(select fee from FeeTable where zip = @zip1
union all
select fee from FeeTable where zip = @zip2) as temp
```

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea what a stored procedure has to do with this.

But the query that you want is:

```
select sum(fee)
from FeeTable
where zip = @zip1 or zip = @zip2;
```

EDIT:

if `@zip1` and `@zip2` were the same *and* you wanted twice the sum of one, for whatever reason (this is what your version would do):

```
select sum(fee) * (case when @zip1 = @zip2 then 2 else 1 end)
from FeeTable
where zip = @zip1 or zip = @zip2;
```